# Enviar e-mail com Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express.js, nodemailer

Estou tentando enviar os dados de um formulário por e-mail, mas quando eu aperto "Submit" ele retorna "Cannot POST /send". Esse é o código do meu formulário:

```
        <ion-item line="none">
          <ion-label color="primary" position="floating" stacked><span translate>Name</span></ion-label>
          <ion-input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item line="none">
          <ion-label color="primary" position="floating" stacked>E-mail</ion-label>
          <ion-input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item line="none" >
          <ion-label color="primary" position="floating" stacked><span translate>Suggestions</span></ion-label>
          <ion-input id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="How can we improve?" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button type="submit" value="submit"><span translate>Submit</span></ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

E o código que estou usando no server-side pra mandar o e-mail:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: '******@gmail.com', // generated ethereal user
        pass: '******'  // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
      from: '"Nodemailer Contact" <ifybook@gmail.com>', // sender address
      to: '********@gmail.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Node Suggestion Request', // Subject line
      text: 'New form!', // plain text body
      html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

      res.render('contact', {msg:'Email has been sent'});
  });
  });

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port} (${env})`));
```

Comment: Pelo que eu vi no código, o seu form, a action deveria ser: `/send`. Segue a minha sugestão para corrigir o problema: `<form id="suggestion-form" method="post" action="/send" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. A mudança aqui é apenas colocar uma "barra" na action do form.

Comment: Realmente estava faltando a barra mesmo, mas mesmo depois que eu coloquei continua retornando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Outra coisa é que está faltando fechar a tag form no html. com `</form>` pelo menos não está presente na pergunta.

Comment: É que eu só coloquei os itens aqui, mas no código original está certinho.

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema seria implementando a abordagem descrita neste código, utilizei [`nodemailer`](https://nodemailer.com/about/) em parceria com [`expressjs`](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/) para fazer o envio de e-mail via um formulário.

Neste código temos duas rotas:

1. rota `/` que apresenta o formulário para envio de e-mail.
2. rota `/sendmail` que faz o envio do email utilizando o nodemailer.

Fiz uma adaptação do seu código para remover os componentes do ionic, mas a lógica e atributos são os mesmos, a diferença é que não utilizamos nenhum framework de interface para desenhar os componentes na tela. O objetivo aqui é ser didático e se atentar à implementação.

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();

const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form id="suggestion-form" method="post" action="/sendmail">
            <label><span>Name</span></label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required/>
            <br>
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required></input>
            <br>
            <label><span>Suggestions</span></label>
            <input id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="How can we improve?" required></input>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" value="submit"><span>Submit</span></button>
        </form>
      </body>
</html>`

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
    },
    auth: {
        user: 'nomedousuario',
        pass: 'senha-do-endereço-de-email'
    },
    logger: false, // log to console
    debug: false // include SMTP traffic in the logs
});
  
sendEmail = (req, res) => {
    const mailmsg = {
        from: 'nomedousuario',
        subject: 'Teste',
        text: 'Mensagem de: ' + req.body.name+ ', email: [' + req.body.email + '] ' + req.body.message,
        to: 'email@teste.com.br'}; // preencher destinatário do email
    
    transporter.sendMail(mailmsg).then((trans) => {
        res.status(200).send('E-mail enviado');
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).send('Houve um erro ao enviar e-mail. Detalhe: '+error);
    });
}
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(html);
})
app.post('/sendmail', sendEmail);
 
try {
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log(`Microsservice listening at http://localhost:${3000}`);
} catch (err) {
    throw err;
}
```

Desta forma temos uma implementação completa do fluxo de envio para o Gmail, seguindo a documentação de configuração de [`transporter do gmail`](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/).

Além dessas configurações, para poder funcionar em seu e-mail é necessário fazer a configuração de utilizar apps menos seguras. Para ativar as aplicações menos seguras em seu email basta seguir as instruções [`deste link`](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cif-less-secure-app-access-is-off-for-your-account), após acessar este link procurar a informação: `If "Less secure app access" is off for your account`. E seguir as instruções daquele link para ativar este modo.

Somente após fazer essas configurações será possível fazer o envio do email com o nodemailer. Caso esta configuração não seja feita será necessário.

Caso não faça esta configuração ficará recebendo sempre uma mensagem de erro como esta

```
{
 "code":"EAUTH",
 "response":"535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a6sm9299103oil.6 - gsmtp",
 "responseCode":535,
 "command":"AUTH PLAIN"
}
```

Mesmo que todos os dados da conta estejam corretos.